# How to input a boolean and return as a boolean?

Tags: java, junit, boolean

Method named `hasAdjacentRepeats` that accepts a `String` as input and returns, as a `boolean`, whether the input has two adjacent characters which are identical.

Like this question said I don't know how to define such a method that returns a  `Boolean`.

Comment: `boolean hasAdjacentRepeats(String input) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what to do make the method

```
boolean hasAdjacentRepeats(String input) 
{
 code
 return [boolean]
}
```

This answer is a method that takes in the string input and then returns boolean either true or false depending on what your algorithm is.

Answer (score 0):

You can make 'boolean' the return type in the declaration of the function, and then within that function return either 'true' or 'false'.

```
public boolean hasAdjacentRepeats(String str) {
    if (something) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution on c#

```
bool hasAdjacentRepeats(String input)
        {
            var firstLetter = input[0];
            int flag = 1;
            foreach (var letter in input)
            {
                if (firstLetter == letter && flag != 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    firstLetter = letter;
                }
                flag = 0;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

You can use an similar algorithm:
the input has two adjacent characters which are identical.